# Unity + Kinect - Current, and active wrapper options?

Tags: unity, kinect

What are some current wrapper solutions for using the Kinect with Unity? The initial primesense one seems not to be in active development.

I'm aware of the Zigfu one, however are there any open-source alternatives?

Comment: Which technology to use questions aren't a good fit for the Q/A format of the site. See the [FAQ] for details.

Comment: In this case I'm asking what the options are, so I can be made aware. I can rephrase the question to remove the "which is the best" part. Otherwise I think the question is very valid. I'm asking if any options exist that fill a niche in a gaming engine for using a different game device to create games

Comment: Without "which is the best" it just becomes a "list of X" question, which has no objective single answer and becomes outdated quickly.

Comment: Outdated list are still often a good jumping off point for future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the oficial Microsoft Kinect SDK? It's a .NET assembly that can be added as reference to a normal C# project.

You can download the SDK from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx

Comment: Interesting, would this work on OSX as well?

Comment: There is an open-source implementation called 'OpenKinect' (http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page). There is also a C# wrapper (http://openkinect.org/wiki/CSharp_Wrapper).